# Programmatically format integer field display

Tags: 7, entities

I am trying to programmatically format how an integer field displays. So far I have only been able to produce "1.00", and I am trying to get it like so: x.xx.x. The content type is "Project" and the field is "Drupal version".

Here is my code:

```
<!-- Display the drupal version with decimals -->
      <?php if (isset($node) && $node->type == 'project'): ?>
          <?php $drupal_version = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_drupal_version', array('label'=>'default')); ?>

          <?php $formatted_drupal_version = number_format((float)$drupal_version, 2); ?>
          <?php echo "Drupal version: " . render($formatted_drupal_version); ?></span>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

output: Drupal version: 1.00

Does anyone know why this is the output, and how I can extend this function number_format to produce something in this format x.xx.x, for example "Drupal version: 7.41.1" ?

Thanks!

Comment: use a text field? Last time I checked integers do not have two periods.

Comment: what should be on the place of the last X? please add real example of desired output.

Comment: hi @NoSssweat! I'm actually trying to alter existing data (without deleting it). So I only want to change the way it's displayed...

Comment: @JurajNemec just updated the description

Comment: so you want `1.00` to become 1.00.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the following code:

```
$drupal_version = (int)$drupal_version; // make sure this is an int
$parts = array();
preg_match('/^(\d{1})(\d{2})(\d+)$/', "$drupal_version", $parts);
array_shift($parts); // get rid of the first element in $parts which is the whole matched string
$formatted_drupal_version = implode($parts, '.');
echo "Drupal version: " . $formatted_drupal_version;
```

As examples, these integers will turn into the following strings:
7411 => 7.41.1
74110 => 7.41.10

Which means, that this code, will work parsing the provided integer from left to right, and collecting, 1 digit for the major version, 2 digits for the medium version, and all the remaining digits for the minor version.

Hope this helps!

P.S.: You question is a bit misleading, as @No Sssweat says, you cannot format an integer like that. That is why string parsing is the only way to provide you with the desired result.

Comment: You're right! I changed my question to be less confusing thank you.

Comment: the variable $drupal_version actually holds an array... Would you know how to access the integer value  from "field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_drupal_version')" ? (I'm new to php)

Comment: If you already have the $node object available, you can simply access the field value from there: $node->field_drupal_version[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']